# How do I install a program that involves make, configure, and build?

Tags: configuration, build, makefile

I knew this day would come, so I guess it is here. (P.S. I am on windows XP).

I am trying to use [this](http://www.thrysoee.dk/laeqed/) program here. I installed it fine, but it doesnt seem to work when I type in equations. So I went back to the site and it says I need JRE version 5.0 or above, (check). Then it also says I need dvipng, which I dont think I have.

So I went to the site it tells me to, ([here](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/dvipng/)), and I downloaded the most recent one, "dvipng-1.14.tar.gz". I unzipped it and I have it all sitting in one directory.

Ok... now what?

Im afraid I need guidance on exactly how to proceed here. The readme and installation instructions say to run "./configure", then "make", etc, I opened the command prompt and did all that but doesnt recognize. I have never had to build in this way, I always used an IDE for compiling C++ programs that I write myself. (Anyway, why am I even having to make an exe why dont they just make one and let us download that?)

Very confused as to what I need to do here, appreciate some step by step help.

Thank you

Comment: 'make' is a linux command. You are on XP.

Comment: p.s. I think you need this... http://www.miktex.org/2.9/setup (rather than the dvipng-1.14.tar.gz as that is for linux systems)

Comment: Sorry, I do not know LINUX unfortunately. The spec is saying "System Requirements

Laeqed requires a Java Runtime Environment (JRE) of version 5.0 or later, a LaTeX system and the dvipng program.

On Linux (Debian) the requirements can be met by running:

$ apt-get install sun-java6-jre texlive dvipng
On Windows, get the latest JRE from java.com and the "Basic MiKTeX" installer, which provides both the LaTeX system and the dvipng program.", but I already have MikTex ... very confused.

Comment: Was the dvipng an optional install when installing MikTex? Maybe try re-installing it.

Comment: p.s. this might also help. http://groups.google.com/group/ankisrs/browse_thread/thread/c0e6d30fc8c4ba96?pli=1

Comment: @Magrangs: I wouldn't necessarily call `make` a linux command. I think it originated on Unix systems, but ports to many other OS's are available, including Windows.

Comment: @Magrangs I got it to work, thank you so much for your help. For anyone else who comes across this, I had to un-install mikTex and select 'no' when it asks you about importing libraries when I re-installed, instead of 'ask me'. I dont know why it worked but it does now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though Mohammad's problem was solved in the comments, I'll have a go at answering his question:

To run a build system that uses `./configure`, you need something that can run shell scripts, as well as the usual suite of unix tools that the script expects, plus a compiler that behaves in the standard sort of way.

The two projects that I know of that do this are [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com) and [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS). cygwin is aimed at creating a full POSIX environment on windows, while MSYS is an add-on to MinGW that aims to provide just the parts needed to run a `./configure` script and build a program.

Comment: @Kelly Thank you Mr Kelly, I have MinGW, but not Cygwin. If I get Cygwin, do I have to do anything to 'link' or associate it with MinGW in this case before I can run ./configure command from its prompt?

Comment: @Mohammad: I made a mistake. The package you want is MSYS, which lets you run MinGW tools (like `gcc`) from a unix-style command line (so you can run the `./configure` script).

Comment: Ok thanks, do I have to do anything special to associate MSYS to MinGW? I mean just install MSYS and since I already have MinGW then it should work ok?

Comment: I haven't used it since the move to `mingw-get`, but this page looks promising: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started